# Delete row using Java PreparedStatement not always working

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

When i'm trying to delete a last row in a table using a PreparedStatement (I'm using a MySQL database), the row wasn't been deleted, I tried to use a `DELETE FROM`... command and a `TRUNCATE` command (using the `executeUpdate()` command), but none of those commands deleted that last row, What should I do, in order to be able to delete that last row?

this is the command i have written:

```
String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM free_time WHERE therapist_id=? AND from=? AND to=? AND date=?";
```

And I have checked that the parameters that i'm sending to the Prepared Statement are correct, but still, the row isn't been deleted.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Some code and (if they exist) errors?

Comment: what last row? last inserted or modified? biggest autoincrement id?

Comment: A code sample would be helpful for diagnosis. A potential issue is that you're working within a transaction and not commiting your changes.

Comment: Please post the command, and the error

Comment: you can edit your question...

Comment: There is no error, everything seems to be working, but still the row wasn't deleted

Comment: this is the command i have written: String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM free_time WHERE therapist_id=? AND from=? AND to=? AND date=?"; And I have checked that the parameters that i'm sending to the Prepared Statement are correct, but still, the row isn't been deleted.

Comment: you can edit your question it's more readable, are you committing?

Comment: I checked the Connection, and the auto-commit property is set to true;

Comment: try committing manually. maybe something else rolls back your action...

Comment: i have tried to commit manually, same results. When i'm deleting and inserting another row it's working but when i'm trying only to delete a row from the table, and to leave it empty, the row is not deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last row doesn't mean anything in a relational database.  You don't need to know how the rows are stored.

You should be using a WHERE clause to identify what you need to DELETE.

I wouldn't recommend TRUNCATE.

Comment: this is the command i have written: 
String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM free_time WHERE therapist_id=? AND `from`=? AND `to`=? AND date=?"; And I have checked that the parameters that i'm sending to the Prepared Statement are correct, but still, the row isn't been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using key words, and obviously suppressing exceptions ;).

```
String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM free_time WHERE therapist_id=? AND `from`=? AND `to`=? AND `date`=?";
```

Comment: What does it mean? I have tried to rewrite the command like this:
DELETE FROM `ThetaOnline`.`free_time` WHERE `free_time`.`therapist_id` = ? AND `free_time`.`from` = ? AND `free_time`.`to` = ? AND `free_time`.`date` = ?; But still, no difference

Comment: The from and to values probably are DATETIME, so easily wrong by a hundredth second. You could test that by a SELECT with the same parameter values and/or some logging.